# Problem in R with GRASS: The input layer has multiple values can I change the code to read all of the values

Tags: r, grass-gis

I am new in the area. I am working with GRASS in R. Now I am trying to load an vector corine land cover data and my before calculated catchment areas of the DEM and the created Stream network. I understand that my error tells me that my input paramters are multiple values, but I am not sure if I need to change a setting or if the code is wrong or need to be changed. I can't find an problem solving answer as I do not understand the GRASS key support on this subject. Anyone understands my question an can help me?

Problem in R with GRASS: The input layer has multiple values can I change the code to read all of the values or do I need to create a layer with all the information before and if so can someone please help me with that

```
for(i in 1:length(locID))
+ print(i)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 11
[1] 12
[1] 13
[1] 14
[1] 15
[1] 16
[1] 17
[1] 18
[1] 19
[1] 20
[1] 21
[1] 22
> cname <- paste0("sites_catchm_", locID[1:22])
> if(cname %in% rast){
+     if(!cname %in% vect){
+       
+       # change raster to vector
+       execGRASS("r.to.vect", flags = c("overwrite","v"),
+                 parameters = list(
+                   input = cname,
+                   output = paste0(cname,"_v"),
+                   type = "area"
+                 ))
+       # calculate area
+       execGRASS("v.db.addcolumn",
+                 parameters = list(
+                   map = paste0(cname,"_v"),
+                   columns = "area double precision"
+                 ))
+       execGRASS("v.to.db",flags = "quiet",
+                 parameters = list(
+                   map = paste0(cname,"_v"),
+                   option = "area",
+                   columns = "area"
+                 ))
+       tarea <- sum(as.numeric(execGRASS("v.db.select",flags = "quiet",
+                                         parameters = list(
+                                           map = paste0(cname,"_v"),
+                                           columns = "area"
+                                         ), intern = T)[-1]))
+     }
+     
+     # intersect  
+     execGRASS("v.overlay", flags = c("overwrite","quiet"),
+               parameters = list(
+                 ainput = paste0("clc_"), 
+                 binput = paste0(cname,"_v"),
+                 operator = "and",
+                 output = "intersect_clc",
+                 olayer = "1,0,0"
+               ))
+     # calculate areas from the features 
+     execGRASS("v.db.addcolumn",
+               parameters = list(
+                 map = "intersect_clc",
+                 columns = "area double precision"
+               ))
+     execGRASS("v.to.db",flags = "quiet",
+               parameters = list(
+                 map = "intersect_clc",
+                 option = "area",
+                 columns = "area"
+               ))
+     # read data from table
+     a <- execGRASS("v.db.select",flags = "quiet",
+                    parameters = list(
+                      map = "intersect_clc",
+                      columns = paste0("CODE_12",",area")
+                    ), intern = T)[-1]
+     a <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(a,split = '\\|'))
+     a <- data.frame(a,  stringsAsFactors = F)
+     a <- apply(a,2,as.numeric)
+     if(class(a) == "matrix"){
+       a <- round(tapply(a[,2],a[,1], sum),2)
+     } else {
+       nam <- a[1]
+       a <- a[2]
+       names(a) <- nam
+     }
+   }
Error in doGRASS(cmd, flags = flags, ..., parameters = parameters, echoCmd = echoCmd,  : 
  Parameter <input> has multiple values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (cname %in% rast) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (!cname %in% vect) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, I think, if even before you get to the execGRASS commands. You're defining `cname` as a list, then trying to use it as an input variable.

```
> locID <- seq(1:22)
> cname <- paste0("sites_catch",locID[1:22])
> str(cname)
 chr [1:22] "sites_catch1" "sites_catch2" "sites_catch3" "sites_catch4" ...
```

Commands like r.to.vect cannot take lists, only a single raster name.

What it seems that you want is to loop thru the rasters. Probably something like this: (Not tested)

```
> library(rgrass7)
Loading required package: sp
Loading required package: XML
GRASS GIS interface loaded with GRASS version: GRASS 7.2.1 (2017)
and location: RADOLAN

> rlist <- execGRASS(cmd="g.list", type='rast', pattern='radar*')
> for (r in attributes(rlist)$resOut)
+ print(r)
# Do all your processing on each raster 'r' here
# change raster to vector
+ execGRASS("r.to.vect", flags = c("overwrite","v"),
+                 parameters = list(
+                 input = r,
+                 output = paste0(r,"_v"), 
+                 type = "area"
+                ))
# etc...
```

Comment: I did the mistake with trying to load all of the sites in at once, and didn't realize the loop can only work for one each time. Unfortenately the loop doesn't seem to work. But I did it each on it's own now. More difficult but I can't find the mistake in the loop. Thanks for your answer.